# How to compute a dual of a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A=M_2(K)$ be the algebra of all $2\times 2$ matrices over $K$. Let $e_1=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $e_2=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then $P=Ae_1=\{ \left( \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \mid a, b \in K\}$.

Let $D(P)=Hom_K(P, K)$. How to compute $D(P)$? I can verify that $f: P \to K, \left( \begin{matrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto a$ is in $Hom_K(P, K)$. Are there other non-zero homomorphisms in $Hom_K(P, K)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $P$ has is a vector space of dimension $2$, and hence so is $D(P)$.  One strategy might be to fix a basis, then take the corresponding dual basis and see how $A$ acts on the dual basis.  If you could describe all the two dimensional modules, you might be able to identify the correct candidate more easily.

Comment: $P$ is just a free module. This is just linear algebra.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $P$ is only a projective $A$ module, not free (since $A$ has dimension $4$ over $K$ while $P$ only has dimension $2$), although it is a free $K$ module.  If the goal is to recognize $D(P)$ as an $A$ module, I believe this is slightly more involved than linear algebra.  Or at least, it isn't a priori clear to me that it isn't.

Comment: @Aaron: The OP is looking for $K$-homomorphisms. $K$ itself is not an $A$-module at all.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: We do not need $K$ to be an $A$-module.  Since $K$ is a central subalgebra of $A$, we can view view $P$ as both an left $A$ module or a left $K$ module, and since the actions commute with each other and $K$ is commutative, we can view it as an $(A,K)$-bimodule.  Viewing the $\hom$ in the def of $D(P)$ as one of right $K$-modules,  More generally, if $X$ is an $(A,B)$-module and $Y$ is an $(A,C)$-module, then $\hom_A(X,Y)$ is a $(B,C)$-module.

Comment: @Aaron: you are putting extra words into the problem that I do not see there (namely "how do I compute $D(P)$ _as a right $A$-module_").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori, $D(P) = \operatorname{Hom}_K(P,K)$ admits the structure of a *right* $A$-module via
$$
 (f \cdot a)(p) := f(a \cdot p), \quad f \in D(P), \; a \in A, \; p \in P.
$$
Since $A$ admits the $K$-algebra anti-automorphism $A \mapsto A^T$, one can moreover realise $D(P)$ as a *left* $A$-module via
$$
 (a \cdot f)(p) := f(a^T \cdot p), \quad f \in D(P), \; a \in A, \; p \in P;
$$
I claim that ${}_A D(P) \cong {}_A P$.

To prove this, first identify ${}_A D(P)$ with ${}_A (e_1 A)$, where $e_1 A$ is endowed with the left $A$-module structure
$$
  a \cdot (e_1 b) := e_1 b a^T, \quad a,b \in A,
$$
and where the dual pairing between $e_1 A \cong D(P)$ and $P = A e_1$ is given by
$$
 \left\langle e_1 a, b e_1 \right\rangle := e_1 a b e_1 \in e_1 A e_1 = K e_1 \cong K, \quad a,b\in A.
$$
Then, the transposition $e_1 a \mapsto (e_1 a)^T = a^T e_1$ yields the necessary isomorphism ${}_A e_1 A \cong {}_A P$.

If you prefer, you can also observe that ${}_A P \cong {}_A K^2$, and hence ${}_A D(P) \cong {}_A (K^2)^\ast \cong {}_A K^2$, where the isomorphism ${}_A (K^2)^\ast \cong {}_A K^2$ is again just transposition, taking row vectors in $(K^2)^\ast$ to column vectors in $K^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth mentioning that $A$ has a unique simple module, up to isomorphism, and so (identifying $A$ with $A^{op}$ as in Branimir Cacic's answer), since $P$ is a simple $A$-module, so is $D(P)$, and hence they are necessarily isomorphic.